# scraping google news with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I used to have a function that was able to scrape the headlines from [google news](https://news.google.com/?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:enb) but it seems that they changed their CSS or something. It doesn't work anymore.

Here's my closest attempt at fixing it:

```
library('rvest')
library('tidyverse')
headlines <- function(){
  message("Here are some of today's headlines:")
  html <- read_html("https://news.google.com/news/?ned=us&gl=US&hl=en")
  headlines = html %>%
    html_nodes(".SbNwzf") %>%
    html_text()

  for(i in 1:10){
    cat(paste("\t",headlines[i],"\n\n"))
    Sys.sleep(1.3)
  }
  headlines

}
headlines()
```

This is pretty close to what I want but I was hoping to get only the headlines. It seems like this is getting the first part of the articles as well.

Also, if anyone has a way of getting just the top headline of each box, that would be preferable. Was trying node '.VDXfz' but it returns blank. I am using [selector gadget](https://selectorgadget.com/)

Thanks!

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672911/how-to-fetch-headlines-from-google-news-using-rvest-r/) answer will be useful

Comment: @Didi Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't work for me. It did, however, give me a little boost to try new things and I solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what ended up working:

```
headlines <- function(){
  message("Here are some of today's headlines:")
  html <- read_html("https://news.google.com/news/?ned=us&gl=US&hl=en")
  headlines = html %>%
    html_nodes('.DY5T1d') %>% # <-- THIS
    html_text()

  for(i in (0:9)*5+1){ # PRINT EVERY 5TH ENTRY
    cat(paste("\t",headlines[i],"\n\n"))
    Sys.sleep(1.3)
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, this depends on google news keeping the format of 1 lead article on a topic and 4 supporting ones. I still was not able to identify a marker for the lead articles so I could pick them out alone.